# Excel VBA and Aliases? Is this possible?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet in Excel that will be imported into an Access database later on. I am getting users to select a value from multiple drop down menus. My problem is, these drop down menu values need to be very specific, and are not very readable, for example:

```
notAttendingSchoolWhy: (choose one)

TOO_YOUNG_FOR_SCHOOL
GRADUATED
NOT_ATTENDING_DUE_TO_DIABETES
NOT_ATTENDING_DUE_TO_FINANCIAL_REASONS
NOT_ATTENDING_FOR_OTHER
```

I'd like these to be a bit more readable, but still be able to be imported into my database. So, I'd like to use something like an alias in Excel where the user sees the 'nice' version, e.g.

> not Attending School Why:
>   Too young for school
>   Graduated
>   etc.etc.

and I can still put the matching version into my database. Any ideas? All help much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: You can use the string `Replace` function to replace the underscores with spaces. You can then use the `LCase` function to convert each answer to its lower-case equivalent, and then the `UCase` function on the *first* character in each answer to captilize it.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for responding. I was concerned that this would change my overall output, so that when I go to import this into the database, it won't be importable. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes.  You'll just need to store the before and after values. I'd use a dictionary object for this and then match back to the original values.

Comment: I provided a sample but at the same time voted to close this question as this is too broad. Check this [StackOverflow question checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to guide you on how you'll construct your next question if ever you have another.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Yes that is possible.
By brute force you can actually do this:

```
Dim whattowrite As String
Select Case Mydropdown.Value ' you didn't mention the type of object you are using
Case "Too young for school"
    whattowrite = "TOO_YOUNG_FOR_SCHOOL"
Case "Some more"
.
.
End Select
Range("YourActualRangeAddress").Value = whattowrite
```

That is not very convenient if you have multiple dropdowns.
So you can do what David commented, you need to store the values (usinng range, array or if you know *Dictionary*) somewhere. I'd take the Range sample since in my opinion is the easiest.

Set up a temporary sheet like this, lets call it `Sheet1`:

[image]

Let us name the ranges as well (see using [Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html))

- Range `A2:A6` will be `Informative`
- Range `B2:B6` will be `Actual`

We can initialize the dropdown value using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With Me.ComboBox21
        .ListFillRange = ThisWorkbook.Names("Informative") _
            .RefersToRange.Address(, , , True)
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

Then we can write a value to a cell or any destination using:

```
Private Sub ComboBox21_Change()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Names("Actual").RefersToRange
    With Me
        .Range("G2").Value = Application.Index(r, .ComboBox21.ListIndex + 1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

**The result would be:**

[image]

There are many possible set up actually. I just hope that this gives you an idea on all of those possibilities.